# Apache2::RequestRec doesn't have 'param' method for Session::Wrapper

Tags: apache, mason

Got an error in the mason handler like this on my new web server which is migrated from apache1 to apache2:

> The 'param_object' parameter
>   ("Apache2::RequestRec=SCALAR(0x7f6541b5af28)") to
>   Apache::Session::Wrapper->new() does not have the method: 'param'

The mason handler is working well for apache1, but for apache2, it looks the object is changed to `Apache2::RequestRec` from `Apache::Request`. But `Apache2::RequestRec` has no method 'param'.

Is there any work around for this? Thanks in advance.

Yang

Answer (score 0):

I know it is late, but try to add

```
args_method   => "mod_perl"
```

to your args for your ApacheHandler object in:

```
HTML::Mason::ApacheHandler->new
```

I believe that cleared it up for me.